# What's more likely with 7 dice - Straight, Full House, or 3-of-a-Kind

Tags: probability, dice, poker

Here's a problem I'm having.

I have 7 dice. I want to rank the difficulty of achieving a particular 5 dice combination after all 7 dice have been rolled.

A straight is when at least 5 of the seven dice are in sequential order.

A full house is when you have at least 3 dice of one number and at least 2 dice of another number.

And a 3 of a kind is when you have 3 dice of one number but NOT a full house.

So the first thing that makes sense to me is that 3-of-a-kind is actually more difficult than a full house after all dice are out.

But the problem I'm having is whether 3-of-a-kind is more difficult or a straight is more difficult. Because if a straight is more difficult, then I want to award the roll as a straight and that changes the probability of seeing a 3-of-a-kind. And if a 3-of-a-kind is more difficult then I want to award the roll as a 3-of-a-kind, not check for straights, then straights become more difficult and the odds switch places.

Should I be checking for these independently from each other? For instance, when you ask how often do I get 3-of-a-kind in poker does it include 4-of-a-kind?

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whether I understand your question. Is it about the
overlap of straight and 3 of a kind? The following scheme might be
helpful anyway.

$\begin{array}{cccccccc}
\text{split-up} &  & \text{full house} & \text{straight} & \text{3 of a kind} & \text{orders} & \text{selections}\\
7 &  &  &  &  & 1 & 6 & 6\\
6|1 &  &  &  &  & 7 & 30 & 210\\
5|2 &  & \text{yes} &  &  & 21 & 30 & 630\\
5|1|1 &  &  &  &  & 42 & 60 & 2520\\
4|3 &  & \text{yes} &  &  & 35 & 30 & 1050\\
4|2|1 &  & \text{yes} &  &  & 105 & 120 & 12600\\
4|1|1|1 &  &  &  &  & 210 & 60 & 12600\\
3|3|1 &  & \text{yes} &  &  & 140 & 60 & 8400\\
3|2|2 &  & \text{yes} &  &  & 210 & 60 & 12600\\
3|2|1|1 &  & \text{yes} &  &  & 420 & 180 & 75600\\
3|1|1|1|1 & \text{consecutive} &  & \text{yes} & \text{yes} & 840 & 10 & 8400\\
3|1|1|1|1 & \text{not consecutive} &  &  & \text{yes} & 840 & 20 & 16800\\
2|2|2|1 &  &  &  &  & 630 & 60 & 37800\\
2|2|1|1|1 & \text{consecutive} &  & \text{yes} &  & 1260 & 20 & 25200\\
2|2|1|1|1 & \text{not consecutive} &  &  &  & 1260 & 40 & 50400\\
2|1|1|1|1|1 &  &  & \text{yes} &  & 2520 & 6 & 15120\\
\text{sum} &  &  &  &  &  &  & 279936\end{array}$

Giving the dice an order there are $6^{7}=279936$ possible outcomes.

To explain: **split-up** $4|2|1$ stands for the possibilities a number
is thrown $4$ times, another number is thrown $2$ times and again
another number is thrown $1$ time. For instance: $1211616$.

Then the numbers $1,2,6$ are **selected** but of course it can be done with
other numbers. There are $6\times5\times4=120$ selections for split-up
$4|2|1$.

Also there are several **orders**. Next to the mentioned $1211616$ we can have $6111261$ or  $1621116$ et cetera. There are $\frac{7!}{4!2!1!}=105$  orders for split-up $4|2|1$.

The product
gives you all possibilities for split-up $4|2|1$ and the probability
that it occurs is $\frac{105\times120}{279936}=\frac{12600}{279936}$.

In two cases I discerned consecutive and not consecutive. For instance at result $4164423$ we are dealing with a split-up $3|1|1|1|1$ but the numbers are not consecutive (hence we do not have a straight, if I understood you well). At result $4564423$ we are also dealing with a split-up $3|1|1|1|1$ and at this result the numbers are consecutive (hence we have a straight).